# Mips store and print from array

Tags: arrays, loops, debugging, mips

I'm new to Mips and need some help. I'm trying to store 5 user input strings into an array, then print them out in that order. But my code prints the last element of the array 5 times instead of printing all elements. I've been trying to debug it, but have  had no luck so far.

```
.data
open:       .asciiz "Enter a series of 5 formulae:\n"
close:      .asciiz "The values are:\n"
array:      .space 100
line:       .space 20



    .text
main:
    # print opening
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, open
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    la $s0, array   # set base of array
    j loopinput


loopinput:
    beq $t0, 20, print
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, line
    li $a1, 20
    syscall
    move $t1, $a0
    sw $t1, 0($s0)  # store word from line into array
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j loopinput



print:
    li $v0, 4   # print closing
    la $a0, close
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    la $s1, array


loopoutput:
    beq $t0, 20, end
    lw $t1, 0($s1)
    li $v0, 4
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    addi $s1, $s1, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j loopoutput



end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: You're reading into the same piece of memory (`line`) during every iteration of `loopInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: You had chosen to pass 8 in v0 in loopinput instead of 5. 5 is used for reading integer.

Issue #2: In
`move $t0 $a0` in loopinput it should be move `move $t0 $v0` as this is where the result of a read `syscall` is stored.

Issue #3: I did not understand the use of line in your code but I am guessing you used it for changing line, for that you could simply declare a string "\n" and then print it after printing your array values.

Issue #4: in loopoutput you have passed 4 in $v0 which prints string, you should pass 1 which prints integer.

Compare it with the code attached below

```
.data
open:       .asciiz "Enter a series of 5 formulae:\n"
close:      .asciiz "The values are:\n"
array:      .space 100
line:       .space 20
lineChange:      .asciiz "\n"



    .text
main:
    # print opening
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, open
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    la $s0, array   # set base of array
    j loopinput


loopinput:
    beq $t0, 20, print
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    la $a0, line
    li $a1, 20
    move $t1, $v0
    sw $t1, 0($s0)  # store word from line into array
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j loopinput



print:
    li $v0, 4   # print closing
    la $a0, close
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    la $s1, array


loopoutput:
    beq $t0, 20, end
    lw $t1, 0($s1)
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, lineChange
    syscall
    addi $s1, $s1, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j loopoutput



end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```