# How to convert from integer to unsigned binary representation using loops in MIPS?

Tags: loops, assembly, binary, mips

I dont understand how to load the values from hi to the array and then print it back .

```
.data 
msg1: .asciiz "Please enter value: "
A:    .space  128

.text

main: 

    li $v0, 4               #print text
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5               #getting user input
    syscall

    move $t1, $v0           #move to different register

    li $v0, 1               #print number out
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

    li $t5, 2

     la $s0, A              #load array 
     div $t1, $t5

loop: 
     mfhi $s1
     beq $s1, $zero, end    #conditions
    
     div $t1, $t5           #divide by 2
     mfhi $s0
     addi $s0, $s0, 4
    
     li      $v0, 1      
     move    $a0, $s1
     syscall
    
     j loop 
    
end:

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: what is this code supposed to do?  A binary conversion?

Comment: If your question is about how to do array references in MIPS, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880006/mips-store-and-print-from-array).

Comment: If your question is how to convert a number to a string of binary digits, then you should look into shifting: with shifting you can go "backwards" from LSB to MSB, storing the result in array, and printing later, or, go "forwards" from MSB to LSB and directly printing each bit with no need to store them first.